# apparent side effects of writeln (“:width” specifier causes question marks in output)

Tags: delphi, io, console-application, delphi-xe2, side-effects

I have the following code (RAD Studio XE2, Windows 7 x64):

```
program letters;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$DEFINE BOO}

const
  ENGLISH_ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

begin
{$IFDEF BOO}
  writeln;
{$ENDIF}
  write(ENGLISH_ALPHABET[1]:3);

  readln;
end.
```

When `{$DEFINE BOO}` directive is turned **off**, I have the following (expected) output *(spaces are replaced with dots for readability)*:

```
..a
```

When the directive is turned **on**, I have the following (unexpected) output:

```
// empty line here
?..a
```

instead of expected

```
// empty line here
..a
```

When I change `const ENGLISH_ALPHABET` to `const ENGLISH_ALPHABET: AnsiString`, the expected output is printed without question character. When `:3` formatting is removed or changed to `:1`, there is no question mark. When the output is redirected to file (either by `AssignFile(Output, 'boo.log')` or from command line), there is no question mark again.

What is the correct explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Same in XE4, a [LF] character is stuffed first in the padding buffer, and converted to a `?`. Strange.

Comment: WriteLn is not Unicode aware, and I have a feeling that's the issue here. The string constant is the default Unicode string type, and the call to WriteLn is not interpreting it correctly. You can test this by changing the definition of the constant to `ENGLISH_ALPHABET: AnsiString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`. If my suspicions are right, the problem should go away.

Comment: @KenWhite: yes, when I change string type to `AnsiString`, there is no question mark (btw it's mentioned in the post). Thanks. Still cannot understand "memory effect", though.

Comment: @LURD I think I understand what's going on.

Comment: @KenWhite I think `Write` and `Writeln` are indeed Unicode aware. They can accept UTF-16 buffers. There's just a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @David: I can see that by your answer. Nicely done. (And I wasn't near a compiler when I wrote that comment, which is why I didn't write an answer - I didn't have a way to investigate.)

Comment: Workaround: `Write(sLineBreak);` instead of `Writeln`.

Comment: Still a problem in Delphi XE6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a rather odd bug in the RTL. The call to `write` resolves to a call to `_WriteWChar`. This function is implemented like this:

```
function _WriteWChar(var t: TTextRec; c: WideChar; width: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  if width <= 1 then
    result := _Write0WChar(t, c)
  else
  begin
    if t.UTF16Buffer[0] <> #0 then
    begin
      _Write0WChar(t, '?');
      t.UTF16Buffer[0] := #0;
    end;

    _WriteSpaces(t, width - 1);
    Result := _Write0WChar(t, c);
  end;
end;
```

The `?` that you see is emitted by the code above.

So, why does this happen. The simplest SSCCE that I can construct is this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
const
  ENGLISH_ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
begin
  writeln;
  write(ENGLISH_ALPHABET[1]:3);
end.
```

So, your first call `writeln` and that resolves to this:

```
function _WriteLn(var t: TTextRec): Pointer;
begin
  if (t.Flags and tfCRLF) <> 0 then
    _Write0Char(t, _AnsiChr(cCR));
  Result := _Write0Char(t, _AnsiChr(cLF));
  _Flush(t);
end;
```

Here you push a single character, `cLF`, ASCII character 10, linefeed, onto the output text record. This results in `t.MBCSBuffer` being fed the `cLF` character. That character is left in the buffer which is fine because `System._Write0Char.WriteUnicodeFromMBCSBuffer` does this:

```
t.MBCSLength := 0;
t.MBCSBufPos := 0;
```

But when `_WriteWChar` executes, it indiscriminately looks in `t.UTF16Buffer`. Which is declared in `TTextRec` like this:

```
type
  TTextRec = packed record 
    ....
    MBCSLength: ShortInt;
    MBCSBufPos: Byte;
    case Integer of
      0: (MBCSBuffer: array[0..5] of _AnsiChr);
      1: (UTF16Buffer: array[0..2] of WideChar);
  end;
```

So, `MBCSBuffer` and `UTF16Buffer` share the same storage.

The bug is that `_WriteWChar` should not look at the content of `t.UTF16Buffer` without first checking the length of the buffer. Something that is not immediately obvious how to achieve because `TTextRec` has not `UTF16Length`. Instead, if `t.UTF16Buffer` contains meaningful content, the convention is that its length is given by `-t.MBCSLength`!

So `_WriteWChar` should perhaps be:

```
function _WriteWChar(var t: TTextRec; c: WideChar; width: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  if width <= 1 then
    result := _Write0WChar(t, c)
  else
  begin
    if (t.MBCSLength < 0) and (t.UTF16Buffer[0] <> #0) then
    begin
      _Write0WChar(t, '?');
      t.UTF16Buffer[0] := #0;
    end;

    _WriteSpaces(t, width - 1);
    Result := _Write0WChar(t, c);
  end;
end;
```

Here is a rather vile hack that fixes `_WriteWChar`. Note that I have not been able to get the address of `System._WriteSpaces` to be able to call it. That's something that could be done if you were desperate to fix this.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;

procedure PatchCode(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(Address, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    Move(NewCode, Address^, Size);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, Address, Size);
    VirtualProtect(Address, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

var
  _Write0WChar: function(var t: TTextRec; c: WideChar): Pointer;

function _Write0WCharAddress: Pointer;
asm
  MOV     EAX, offset System.@Write0WChar
end;

function _WriteWCharAddress: Pointer;
asm
  MOV     EAX, offset System.@WriteWChar
end;

function _WriteWChar(var t: TTextRec; c: WideChar; width: Integer): Pointer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if width <= 1 then
    result := _Write0WChar(t, c)
  else
  begin
    if (t.MBCSLength < 0) and (t.UTF16Buffer[0] <> #0) then
    begin
      _Write0WChar(t, '?');
      t.UTF16Buffer[0] := #0;
    end;

    for i := 1 to width - 1 do
      _Write0WChar(t, ' ');
    Result := _Write0WChar(t, c);
  end;
end;

const
  ENGLISH_ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

begin
  @_Write0WChar := _Write0WCharAddress;
  RedirectProcedure(_WriteWCharAddress, @_WriteWChar);

  writeln;
  write(ENGLISH_ALPHABET[1]:3);
end.
```

I submitted [QC#123157](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123157).

Comment: Thanks for analysis! I'm not sure how to formulate QC report - could you submit it?

Comment: You don't need a string constant, just `aChar = 'a';` Was just going to post same answer! Any width specifier > 1 produces the error.

Comment: @stannic Sure, I'll submit the report.

Comment: @LURD Thanks. I'll make sure I submit a truly minimal SSCCE in the report.

Comment: Any idea if this is fixed in XE7?  The patch works great btw, thanks @DavidHeffernan.

Comment: @ChrisThornton Not fixed in XE7