# Delphi DXE6 Console App Using ":width" specifier shows question marks in output

Tags: delphi, console-application, string-formatting, delphi-xe6

I have encountered some weirdness while converting some old (writeln) reports to DXE6 (just trying to rebuild and run, nothing fancy).
There are lots of "layout by brute-force" statements to insert spacing, using the convention where you write/writeln a single space, with a width specifier.  ex: write(' ':10);
When I do that, I get ? on the printout, and when I made a new console app to test with, I was also getting ? on the console output.  Here's my sample test, with output:

```
program Project3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
begin
  Writeln('.....','5a');
  Writeln('.':5,'5b');
end.
```

Expected Output:

```
.....5a
    .5b
```

Actual Output:

```
.....5a
?    .5b
```

As you can see, it DOES give me the spacing, but it also throws in an extra ? up front.  I had the same result under 32 vs 64.  Does anyone know what's going on?  I could obviously convert all of my space formatting to hard-coded blanks, but that's a drag.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286800/apparent-side-effects-of-writeln)

Comment: As the link given by @davea says, any width specifier >1 after a WriteLn produces this error. You can use the patch given by David to circumvent.